# Interpreting bias variance with accuracy in learning curves

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cart, bias-variance-tradeoff

I plotted the accuracy of a Decision Tree model with varying depths.

I see that as the depth increases, the delta between the training and test set starts to increase to a point where they never touch.

I'm confused about how I interpret this in terms of bias/variance. Specifically, I think the bias increases because the tree is overfitting. But variance would stay the same because the test curve plateaus.

[image: learning curves]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the depth increases the bias is low, but the variance increases as the tree is particularly suited for the training data. The variance on the training data is less (as you trained for that). So you see for the training, accuracy is close to 1 always, but due to low bias and high variance for the test, the accuracy is stagnating at 0.8 and they never meet.